# Is there a way to perform a web search from within a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to compare the value of cell contents with web search results without manually doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Search Scraper](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-web-scraping/28450/) uses the ImportXML() function to scraper results. You put the search keyword in a cell and then the ImportXML to fetch the page titles for the query.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=Hello+World", "//h3[@class='r']");
```

For fetching the page links, the XPath would change.

```
=IMPORTXML(URL, "//h3/a/@href")
```

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at that site, and I think that should work. Thanks!